# Customizing axis titles in Seaborn pairplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to customize axis titles in a Seaborn pairplot, e.g., I would like to use the formatted versions (r'$I_{bs}$') and (r'$k_{HL}$') instead of "Ibs" and "kHL" which are the column titles in the dataframe I use to generate the plot. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I named columns using formatted strings in defining the dataframe I used to create the pairplot:
df_red=pd.DataFrame(DataMatrix_red,columns=['shape',r'$d_n$',r'$\nu_s$',r'$D_s$[%]',r'$I_{{bs}}$',r'$k_{{VssL}}$',r'$k_{{HL}}$'])